# 500 Error only one one page in the WP admin

Tags: fatal-error

Looking for possible solutions, because I'm pretty much lost as to why it happens.

In WP Admin, all my pages, when I want to modify them, are OK. But one throws a 500 error.

What could be the problem? The same code is loaded in all pages, AFAIK.

So how can one 500, when the others are ok?

Plugins are:

- ACF
- Contact Form 7
- oAuth Twitter feed for developers
- Regenerate Thumbnails
- Transient Manager
- WP Mail Logging
- WPML
- Yoast

Comment: ____which one ?

Answer (score 2):

It means you have a PHP syntax error. You need to consult the logs or turn on debug mode. In wp-config.php in your root wordpress directory, find the line as follows:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
```

and change it to:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

Refresh your page that appears blank to find the error. If it still does not show up, it means you may need to change your php.ini settings to display errors.

Comment: This is right.  You could also just check the error log.

Answer (score 1):

Found out what it was:

My ACF was writing a novel every time the page was saved, and because of the excess of heavy revisions it crashed.

I installed the WP-Sweep plugins, and swept the revisions.